# post request returns empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send form data to the backend using fetch API but when I console.log my `request.body` it returns an empty object `{}`. What I was trying to send to my backend was the firstname, lastname, email, and message the user inputted. Why isn't the object containing the data. Where did I go wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
//backend
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at port 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({
  limit: '1mb'
}));

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
  console.log('I got a request') //Prints I got a request
  console.log(request.body); //Prints {} (empty object)
});
```

```js
//frontend
function proccessContactMessage() {
  firstName = document.getElementById('contactUsFirstName').value
  lastName = document.getElementById('contactUsLastName').value
  email = document.getElementById('contactUsEmail').value
  message = document.getElementById('contactUsMessage').value

  const data = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    message
  };
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', options);
}
```

```html
<form class="formContactUs">
  <div class="contactUsTitleCon">
    <h2 class="contactUsTitle">Contact Us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsFirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactUsFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsLastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactUsLastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactUsEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsMessage">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="contactUsMessage" placeholder="Enter Message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="contactUsSubmitBtnCon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contactUsSubmitBtn" onclick="proccessContactMessage()">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you test if it makes a difference if you end the request by sending a response? So, after console.log(request.body); put response.send('{"message":"Sending back a message..."}');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand from our exchange of comments in my first answer, the problem comes from the CORS. If so, try this:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    callback(null, true);
  },
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true
};

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: yes this fixed it. but when I try to send back a response back to the front end I get error ```response.json is not a function```. What I did was ```    response.json({
        status: 'success',
        email: data.email,
        firstName: data.firstName
    });``` on my server and ```const response = fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', options);
    const json = response.json();
    console.log(json);``` on my frontend. why is it not working? @Ahmad Moussa

Comment: you dont need to do response.json() in the frontend, just response, or JSON.stringify(response), try firstly to console.log(response)

Comment: JSON.parse(response) sorry !

Comment: it returns an error ``` Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```@Ahmad Moussa

Comment: Well, the fetch method return a promise, so, try this code: fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('data', data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('error', err);)

Comment: thanks for your help! That worked. @Ahmad Moussa

Answer (score 3):

Remove `mode: 'no-cors'` from the `options`.

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: I am assigning ```mode: 'no-cors'``` because I have to allow cross-origin for my fetch ```http://localhost:3000/api``` when is assign ```/api``` on same-origin I get error ``` POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/api 405 (Method Not Allowed)```. @zx01

Answer (score 1):

[The `no-cors` mode doesn't support the `Content-Type: application/json` header](https://evertpot.com/no-cors/). [Try to set up a CORS header](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) and remove the `mode: 'no-cors'` property.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need a body parser ! You can use the `body-parser` or the `express.urlencoded()`.

Try this:

In your app.js:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));// we need to register a parser, to parse the incoming request body !
```

Or, you can replace that with:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
```

Then, you can do:

```
console.log(req.body);
```

Comment: bodyParser is included with express now. I don't need to require bodyParser. @Ahmad Moussa

Comment: @seriously, so why you didnt add it into your code ?
If you dont want to use the body-parser, you should do: app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies

Comment: ```body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option``` I get this. @Ahmad Moussa

Comment: @seriously, try this: app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

Comment: I tried it, that is not the issue.  The issue is from ```mode: 'no-cors'``` it returns an opaque response hence ```{}```. I tried to add ``` 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'``` to allow cors but it's not giving access to it. @Ahmad Moussa

Comment: I added another answer resolving the issue of CORS, BUT, I'm pretty sure that you will also need to have a body-parser, that's why I kept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the function proccessContactMessage() you defined data as:

```
  const data = {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    message
  };
```

But this is not a valid JSON object.

```js
//frontend
function proccessContactMessage() {
  firstName = document.getElementById('contactUsFirstName').value
  lastName = document.getElementById('contactUsLastName').value
  email = document.getElementById('contactUsEmail').value
  message = document.getElementById('contactUsMessage').value

  const data = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: email,
    message: message
  };

  console.log(data);
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', options);
}
```

```html
<form class="formContactUs">
  <div class="contactUsTitleCon">
    <h2 class="contactUsTitle">Contact Us</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsFirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactUsFirstName" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsLastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactUsLastName" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactUsEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="contactUsMessage">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="contactUsMessage" placeholder="Enter Message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="contactUsSubmitBtnCon"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary contactUsSubmitBtn" onclick="proccessContactMessage()">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: this doesn't fix it. @chrwahl

Comment: @seriously at least it is a good start. I didn't consider the backend. Maybe some of the other answers can help there.